# AES-GSM mode Decryption issue in flutter(dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, aes-gcm

I am facing one issue with dart unable to decrypt data for AES-GCM mode with an authentication password.
Below is my dart code:

```
    // Cipher Text Generated by Java.
String cipherText = "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";

// PassPhare or IV pass Generated by Java.
String passPhare = "myLfN7pToARn4t33RyZwAw==";

// Private Key Used by Both Java and dart.
String privateKey = "DGq1tmmtiXXlCtBAFpFuGZbdWolHcna7kbRJTbTIw4Y=";
```

I dont know how to decrypt the cipherText with above supported keys in the Flutter(dart) language.
Since I am a newbie in flutter, Pls could someone help me to guys to decrypt the above data.

Thanks

Comment: GCM uses a tag that is needed for decryption and that you did not post. Often the tag is appended to the ciphertext (e.g. as with JCA/JCE). But even assuming this (by applying the default tag length), decryption fails. Post the Java code used for encryption.

Comment: In my java code, I used a 128-bit tag length. @Topaco we need AES-GCM mode for decryption but the solution written in this thread used CBC mode, Unable to get the decrypted text.

Comment: As already said, post the encryption code. The few data you posted are not enough to answer the question.

Comment: Hi, @Topaco there is my java code.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73769076/aes-gcm-mode-in-java

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code here (and delete the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73769076/9014097)). Also, the code is incomplete. The generation of `secretKey` and `iv` are missing, as well as the implementation of `bytesToHex()`. So the code is not executable.

Comment: Furthermore, the posted ciphertext has not been generated with the posted code using the posted key and IV (then it would have to be decryptable accordingly, which is not the case). So please post the plaintext from which the posted ciphertext should have been generated or consistent test data.

Comment: Hi, @Topaco please check the below code.

Comment: Please edit your question, add the code at the end of your question and delete an answer that is not an answer.

Comment: The Java code does indeed use AES in GCM mode. But it also uses a key derivation, namely PBKDF2 with HMAC/SHA256, which was not clear from your post so far. For decryption, this key derivation must also be implemented on the Dart side. The derived key is then used to perform the AES/GCM decryption. Try porting to Dart with this information and if you get stuck, post your code and describe the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with the [pointycastle](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle) package (and [convert](https://pub.dev/packages/convert) because your ciphertext is hex):

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:convert/convert.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/block/aes.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/block/modes/cbc.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/pointycastle.dart';

void main() {
  String cipherText =
      "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";
  String iv = "myLfN7pToARn4t33RyZwAw==";
  String secret = "DGq1tmmtiXXlCtBAFpFuGZbdWolHcna7kbRJTbTIw4Y=";

  final binaryCipherText = Uint8List.fromList(hex.decode(cipherText));
  final binaryIV = base64Decode(iv);
  final binarySecret = base64Decode(secret);

  final cipher = CBCBlockCipher(AESEngine());

  cipher.init(
    false,
    ParametersWithIV(
      KeyParameter(binarySecret),
      binaryIV,
    ),
  );

  final binaryPlaintext = cipher.process(binaryCipherText);

  print('plaintext: ${hex.encode(binaryPlaintext)}');
}
```

Comment: According to the OP, the GCM mode is used and not the CBC mode. But even for CBC the code does not work, it only decrypts the first block.